# How can i show a pair forms a semigroup?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

An operation . is defined on the set $Z×Z$, ie. the set containing all pairs of integers by:

$(u,v).(x,y)=(u+v,v.y)$

How can i show that the pair ($Z×Z$, . ) forms a semigroup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A semigroup is defined as a set with a closed associative binary operation. Since the operation is well defined and close, it is only left to check that it is associative as well.

But that is immediate since both sum and multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}$ are associative, and an operation defined in two coordinates is associative iff each coordinate is associative.

Comment: thanks but if i wanted to find the netural element of the semigroup and  all invertible elements of the monoid ($Z$ x$ Z$, .) ?

Comment: If you want a unity element then that's a monoid, and if besides you want every element to have an inverse then that's a group. Check the element $\;(0,1)\;$ .